# What can cause Hive's where clause not to have an effect?

Tags: hive

I have this seemingly straightforward query.

```
SELECT
     table1.one 
FROM 
    (SELECT
       user, 
       1 AS one
    FROM 
       users
    WHERE date=${hiveconf:TODAY}
    DISTRIBUTE BY user.id
    SORT BY user.id
    ) table1
WHERE table1.one < 0;
```

Surprisingly, this returns all rows in the `users` table:

```
Execution completed successfully
Mapred Local Task Succeeded . Convert the Join into MapJoin
OK
1
1
1
```

As table1.one is clearly 1 and thus table1.one < 0 is false, I'd expect no rows to be returned. How could that happen?

**EDIT:**
When I add table1.one < 0 to the select clause, I get

```
Mapred Local Task Succeeded . Convert the Join into MapJoin
OK
1   false
1   false
1   false
```

**SECOND EDIT:**
Removing WHERE date=${hiveconf:TODAY} (which was unnecessary because that was a partition attribute anyway) fixed this weird behavior. Not sure what the cause was.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this with one of my hive tables, but I get no rows, as expected.  If you add `, table1.one < 0` to your outer select, do you get `true` or `false`?  Not sure what that'll prove, but when a program seems like it's telling me lies I sometimes find asking it the same question in a different way helps me figure out what's going on. :)

Comment: @TimGoodman: Thanks for taking your time. I followed your advice, and I get false! So weird...

Comment: Very weird.  Forgive me for asking, but you're sure this is an exact copy of the query you ran?  A misplaced semicolon before the `WHERE` would explain it.  Or if this is a simplified version, and the real `WHERE` clause has some misplaced parentheses or something.  Short of that, I'm stumped.

Comment: @TimGoodman: Thanks! I double checked but the query seems indeed exactly the same (unless it has weird encoding issues?). Weirdly, when I got rid of the inner WHERE clause, it worked as expected (see second edit). Have no idea why this is the case though...

Comment: I'm wondering if it has to do with it being a local task.  I found this bug report that sounds similar to what you're experiencing (although the query that triggered it was a bit different): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3592

Comment: @TimGoodman: I reproduced this in an EMR cluster. I'll file a bug report. Thanks for the help!!